# Call Method From BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I hate that my first question seems to have been answered many times, but I'm still having a tough time getting my head around how to call a method using BackgroundWorker.

I'm processing a very large text file using a series of classes and methods. The entire process is kicked off after the user selects a tool strip item. Sequentially, it goes like this:

- User selects the tool strip item
- User selects a file to be processed via a dialog box
- The action starts

I think I can wrap everything into BackgroundWorker from the moment the user pops the initial dialog box, but what I'd like to do for now is just put the method where all the heavy lifting is done into its own instance of BackGroundWorker. I'll add a ProgressBar, too, but I think I can handle that if I can just get the BackgroundWorker process rolling.

From the top (pseudocode used for example purposes. Much omitted for brevity):

```
private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string fileName = openSingleFile.FileName;
     processFile(fileName); 
}

static public void processFile(string fileName)
{
// many vars/loops exist but not shown

    foreach (data in bigData)
    {
        processItem(stringA, stringB); // <-- this method is where the expensive work is done 
        x++; 
    }  
}
```

I've created an instance of BackgroundWorker...:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Things go here
}
```

...and I've tried too many things to list, so I've gone back to the beginning for the presentation above.

If I'm understanding BackgroundWorker, I'll need to do the following:

- Replace processItem(stringA, stringB) in the above code with something like:

  `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(processItem(stringA, stringB));`

...and then do some type of DoWork call?
...and then do some type of RunWorkerCompleted call?

Not sure why my brain is freezing, but I'm embarrassed at the amount of time I've spent on this with no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Without StackOverflow, I would have been DOA a long time ago.

FYI: I've referenced other SO posts, MSDN, and DotNetPerls examples. I'm just missing something conceptually, I suppose.

Comment: Don't forget to tie up all of your events.
bw.DoWork += 
    new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.ProgressChanged += 
    new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += 
    new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Replace processItem(stringA, stringB) in the above code with something like...

No, that's how you got in trouble.  You most definitely want to move the processFile() call to the worker.  There is no perceivable benefit from running processItem() in a worker, at least not in the snippet you posted.  And doing so is difficult, it would require starting more than one worker.  One for each item.  Having a lot of workers that each do little work is not very healthy.  If it is really necessary then you don't want to use BackgroundWorker, you'll want an entirely different approach with several Threads that consume packets of work from a thread-safe queue.  Don't go there if you can avoid it.

The only non-trivial problem to solve is passing the string that processFile() needs.  Luckily BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() has an overload that takes a single object.  Pass your string.  Obtain its value in your DoWork event handler, casting e.Argument back to a string.  Thus:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        string path = (string)e.Argument;
        processFile(path);
    }

    private void processToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(openSingleFile.FileName);
        processToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        processToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the answer, including explanation. Passing the variable FileName was, in fact, a problem that I was having trouble understanding, but failed to note in my question. It was tough picking an answer, as another example provided the complete code for my solution. It seems incredibly lazy of me to choose based on that, so you get the nod for your comments. While I have everything working, I wish I could say that I fully comprehend **why** it's working, but that's another question. Best regards-L.I.A.

Answer (score 1):

Starting up a new background worker is an expensive operation.  You don't want to be starting one for each iteration of a loop.  Instead, put the entire loop inside of a single background worker's scope.

When `ToolStripMenuItem_Click` is run create your background worker, have `processFile` be what is done in the `DoWork` event handler.

Make sure that when doing that work you're really just doing that work, not updating the UI.  You'll want to separate business logic from the user interface.  If you want to update the UI with some current progress then call `ReportProgress` and ensure that there is an event handler to properly update the UI.

If you need to update the UI when the work is all done then you can do so in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  If the work you are doing generates some result that is used to update the UI use the `Result` property of the background worker to pass it from the `DoWork` method to the completed handler.

Comment: Thank you, the points you've made are noted and helped contribute to my understanding of spawning a new thread and its implications, in general. I appreciate you taking the time to provide your input, though I did select another answer that more completely answered the question (you gave me more credit than I deserved re: being able to implement the solution without further information. In other words, it's me, not you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
BackgroundWorker bgw;
```

In the Load event or constructor:

```
bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
//bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.ProgressChanged += bgw_ProgressChanged;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

/

```
    private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = openSingleFile.FileName;

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(fileName);
    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = (string)e.Argument;

        processFile(fileName);
    }

    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;

        //Update progressbar here
    }

    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Job completed
    }
```

Comment: I chose another answer because of the explanation given, but please note that your code directly led to my solution working, notably the instructions for including the BackgroundWorker info in the Load event. It was VERY hard choosing an answer - I even slept on it. W/out your code, I would have spent more time on my solution, but w/out the explanation in the answer I chose, I would just have been copying and pasting the solution w/out furthering my understanding. Please be aware that not choosing your answer was a tough call....thank you again.

Comment: I was wondering if we could call a function from a async worker like the processFile method here or will it be running the new thread as well or on the main thread?